# Не отправляется GET запрос из Android приложения

Tags: java, android, get

Я начинающий разработчик. Я нигде не смог найти ответ на этот вопрос.
Я решил написать программу для сокращения ссылок для Android.
Нашёл метод отправки **GET** запроса, который **работал в eclipse**.

```
URL url;
HttpURLConnection conn;
BufferedReader rd;
String line;
String result = "";
try {
   url = new URL("http://site.ru/2.php?user=55");
   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
   rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
   while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
      result += line;
   }
   rd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

После этого в основном классе eclipse написал собственный код (адрес сервиса заменю на **example.com**):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Gniral {
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Через сколько часов ссылка будет удалена? 0 для отключения этой опции");
        int removeTime = in.nextInt();
        int id = 3900;
        System.out.println("Введите ссылку, которую нужно сократить");
        String url = in.next();
        String ping = "http://rlu.ru/index.sema?a=api&del=" + removeTime + "&preview=1&platn_user_id=" + id + "&platn_short=1&link=" + url;
        System.out.println(GetHTTP.getHTML(ping));
    }
}
```

**В Eclipse программа работает** правильно и выдаёт короткую ссылку.

Убедившись в том, что всё работает правильно я создал проект в AndroidStudio.
Выдал приложению разрешение на интернет:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Файл манифеста целиком выглелит ьак:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.sccraft.urlshortner"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Решил поместить метот в класс MainActivity.
В окне приложения (Activity) запрашиваются теже самые данные, что и в проекте eclipse я только добавил возможность выбора ID пользователя.
В итоге класс MainActivity у меня выгледит так:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String developerID = "3900"; //Мой ID на RLU.RU
    EditText uid;
    EditText url;
    EditText remove;
    EditText result;
    String URL1;
    String id;
    String removeTime;
    String res;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        uid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uid);
        url = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);
        remove = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.removeLink);
        result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.res);
    }

    public void shortenURL(View view) {
        URL1 = url.getText().toString();
        id = uid.getText().toString();
        if (id.equals("")) id = developerID;
        removeTime = remove.getText().toString();
        if (removeTime.equals("")) removeTime = "0";
        String ping = "http://rlu.ru/index.sema?a=api&del=" + removeTime + "&preview=1&platn_user_id=" + id + "&platn_short=1&link=" + url;
        //String ping = "google.com";
        res = getHTML(ping);
        result.setText(res);
    }

    public String getHTML(String urlToRead) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        BufferedReader rd;
        String line;
        String result = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(urlToRead);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStreamReader insr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            rd = new BufferedReader(insr);
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            rd.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Conection error";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Про этот класс AndroidStudio сообщило, что в нём **нет ни одной ошибки** и ни одного предупреждения:
[image: Проверка AndroidStudio на наличие ошибок и неиспользованных переменных и тд]

При попытке сократить URL приложение выдаёт ответ при исключении.
Это лог (ничего в нём не менял):

```
12/03 18:00:41: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "ru.sccraft.urlshortner/ru.sccraft.urlshortner.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 6001 on device Nexus_6_API_25_x86 [emulator-5554]
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/ru.sccraft.urlshortner-1/lib/x86
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is ru.sccraft.urlshortner, real application class is null.

              [ 12-03 18:00:41.334  1524: 1545 D/         ]
              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x93952980, tid 1545
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/ru.sccraft.urlshortner-1/lib/x86
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
E/EGL_emulation: tid 6018: eglSurfaceAttrib(1174): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9a741d00, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
W/System.err:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:187)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:156)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:98)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:345)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243)
W/System.err:     at ru.sccraft.urlshortner.MainActivity.getHTML(MainActivity.java:56)
W/System.err:     at ru.sccraft.urlshortner.MainActivity.shortenURL(MainActivity.java:42)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Почему происходит исключение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется ты выполняешь свой код в главном потоке `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, попробуй создать отдельный поток для этого

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало!
Пришлось написать немного индусского кода.